# Getting the Adoble LiveCycle Java libraries from an Adobe X Pro disc

Tags: adobe, livecycle, xfa

I need to pre-fill an Adobe LiveCycle form and then provide it to a user for further editing, fully functional (the form is rather complex, including JS scripts and xmls). From reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com) and on Adobe forums is seems there are two possible solutions:

1. iText - likely expensive.
2. Get hold of the Adobe Java libraries from when they shipped with Adobe Pro.

I can buy an Adobe X Pro disc. Does anybody know if the disc contains the libraries and whether that would indeed solve my use case? I know it's a long time ago!

Any other suggestions would be appreciated. I do not have control of the template - it is authored by a government entity and is a requirement for certain types of filing.

I have tried to use pdftk, pypdf, pypdf2 and pdfrw but they only handle acroforms. Decrypting the pdf and changing / adding values disable PDF functionality, even if the lengths of the fields do not change as to nor render the pdf invalid.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for the feedback, this is very frustrating. The hope with the CD is not the Adobe application itself but rather that it [includes additional LiveCycle Java software](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-discussions/what-product-replaces-livecycle-designer/m-p/8750345). Our company has a business accounting application for Romania where all forms are in this format. We need to pre-fill with application data, after which accountants make change and sign electronically. Our competitors do it, presumably with the old software, hence it should be possible.

Comment: The form is "Soft A" on [this government page](https://static.anaf.ro/static/10/Anaf/Declaratii_R/1002_5_2023.html), which links to the xml schemas as well. Do you have a reference for how injection works?